# redirect to custom php file after custom contact form is submitted in Magento

Tags: forms, magento, action

I made a CMS page to include a form I created but want the form action to send to /template/contacts/report.phtml

Currently I have this in my form but I know its not right.

```
<form action="report.phtml" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Your 'action' can NOT be report.phtml (which is a template file), you should post your values to a controller. Take a look @ app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php

Comment: This is an addition to the existing contact page. Do I just need to add new values to app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide me with more info on what you are trying to do. You could have many different form posting to contacts indexController

Comment: I have a custom form I created and after user clicks submit I would like to connect the form to report.phtml to process the form. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Normally a '.phtml' is for display propose only and not for business logic (such as processing form). to display a '.phtml' you will need to display it using a controller action. So you would either  need to create a custom module with a controller or reuse contacts

Comment: Is there a way process the form to report.php without a controller? I basically just want the form to be emailed once the user clicks submit.

Answer (score -1):

Magento has built in magento standard contact form. You can access it from browser www.yourdomain.com/contacts

That's managed by the controller in *app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/indexController.php* and the function called

> public *function* indexAction()

and the action on the form is in http://www.yourdomain.com/contacts/index/post/ which is managed by the same controller and a function called

> public *function* postAction()

If your aim to have completely custom form (by adding extra fields), the Magento way, you need to create an extension and have your own controllers that you can access it from browser.

or

the hacking way, you can create new function called customAction() with the same code with postAction(). you can copy *app/code/**core**/Mage/Contacts/controllers/indexController.php* and create new file in *app/code/**local**/Mage/Contacts/controllers/indexController.php*

and copy the whole

> public function postAction(){

until the close of the function.

> }

And paste it and rename the function customAction(). And if you want customise redirection. you can change the code inside your customAction()

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

to

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
$this->_redirect('http://yourdomain/redirect_url');
```

And the action on your form you can pointed to http://www.yourdomain.com/contacts/index/custom/

Hope that's help.